# GTK: How to get the nicks and values from a GSchema enum programmatically

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I have the following GSchema:

```xml
<schemalist gettext-domain="example">
    <enum id="com.example.unit.temperature">
        <value nick="Celsius" value="0"/>
        <value nick="Fahrenheit" value="1"/>
    </enum>
    <schema id="com.example.corefreqgtk" path="/com/example/">
        <key name="unit-of-temperature" enum="com.example.corefreqgtk.unit.temperature">
            <default>'Celsius'</default>
            <summary>Unit of temperature</summary>
            <description>The unit of temperature used across the app</description>
        </key>
    </schema>
</schemalist>
```

And I'm looking for a way to get the `nick`s and `value`s of the enum `com.example.unit.temperature` programmatically.

What I would like to do is to bind the `unit-of-temperature` key to a `ComboBoxText` to allow the user to select the unit of temperature, but I would like to avoid to define twice the enum inside the GScheme and in code.

My goal would be to initialize the `ComboBoxText` reading the possible values directly form the [`GSettings`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/gio/GSettings.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GSettingsSchema` to gather the data inside a GSettings schema. For keys associated with enumeration values, [`g_settings_schema_key_get_range()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-GSettingsSchema-GSettingsSchemaSource.html#g-settings-schema-key-get-range) will return all possible values as an array.